# if the home property is specified the routes table cannot include an entry for /

Tags: flutter

Getting this error with this code:

```
void main() => runApp(RouteTestApp());

class RouteTestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      home: FirstScreen(), 
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
        '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The following assertion was thrown building MaterialApp(dirty, state: _MaterialAppState#a959e):
I/flutter (24918): If the home property is specified, the routes table cannot include an entry for "/", since it would
I/flutter (24918): be redundant.
I/flutter (24918): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart':
I/flutter (24918): Failed assertion: line 172 pos 10: 'home == null ||
I/flutter (24918):          !routes.containsKey(Navigator.defaultRouteName)'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The solution is to remove the **home** property, since it can cause problems if you add the **routes** property.

```
class RouteTestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
        '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set none as '/' code bellow will help you when test widgets with navigation, and still work.

```
final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  '/one': (BuildContext context) => PageOne(),
  '/two': (BuildContext context) => PageTwo(),
  ...
};

runApp(MaterialApp(initialRoute: '/one', routes: appRoutes));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The solution for the error lies within the error description itself: `'If the home property is specified, the routes table cannot include an entry for "/"'`. This essentially means that you should either specify the home property or include '/' as the home screen in the routes, but not both. Having both specified would create redundancy.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Screen0(),
      // initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // '/': (context) => Screen0(),
        '/first': (context) => Screen1(),
        '/second': (context) => Screen2(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```